# 1.My problem in code is that when i input integers 75 and 100 it did not show my desired output

Tags: c++, if-statement, integer

```
/*when you will enter any number between 0-100 .
There are four ranges and the program will show in which range your number lies*/ 

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
  
int main()
{
    int number;
      
    cout << "Enter your number between 0-100\n";
    cin >> number;
    if(number <= 25 || number == 0)
       {
        cout << "your number is between 0-25\n";
       } 
     else if (number > 25 || number <= 50)
       { 
        cout << "your number is between 25-50\n";
       } 
     else if (number > 50 || number <= 75)
       { 
        cout << "your number is between 50-75\n";
       }
     else if(number >75 || number <= 100)
       {
       cout << "your number is between 75-100\n";
       }
       else
       {
       cout<<"number is not between 0-100\n";
       }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't add random language tags.

Comment: Your conditions are wrong. Take some time to think about them.

Comment: And for future question please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: In an if-else chain there's no need to check the complement of the previous if in the next one. So if `if(number <= 25)` fails, `number` *must* be >25... Removing these obsolete checks would at the same time fix your `||`/`&&` mismatch as you'd drop it anyway. Still you should get to understand what made your checks fail, you'll likely need this knowledge at some point of time in the future...

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With a debugger you can execute the program at your speed and watch what the program does as it does it. Typical usage is start the program in the debugger and use a breakpojnt to make it stop before the region you wish to inspect more closely. Make sure the initial conditions are correct. If they aren't, the bug ain't where you thought it was (or you have more than one bug). Step through the region of interest line by line, keeping an eye out for the unexpected like the program taking the wrong path or storing the wrong value.

Comment: Hint for understanding, considering my previous comment: If first `if` fails, `number` *must* be > 25 – so if you get to second if, your first condition is *always* true. What is `true || something`???

Comment: Side note: first if should contain `0 <= number && number <= 25` – be aware that e. g. -7 is unequal to 0 as well as <= 25, so this one would be caught by first if, too.

Answer (score 2):

The second `if` will always fire if the first `if` did not. Reason is it should not be `OR`, `||`, but and `AND`, `&&`, same with the remaining tests.

Comment: OP needs `if(number >= 0 && number <= 25)` as the first test to be able to claim `your number is between 0-25`.

Comment: Yup. you're quite right.